# Slidedown jquery is not working in chrome?

Tags: jquery, slidedown, mouseenter

SlideDown and Slideup is working for firefox and not working for chrome.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#caption").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#caption").slideDown(500);
    });             
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

SlideDown 
and Slideup is 
working for firefox and not working for chrome

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#caption").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#caption").slideDown(500);
    });             
});
</script>
```

Comment: but its same as above question :O